# partial derivative of entry $x_k$ in vector $x$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

My general question is on what to do with a scalar result from a partial derivative.

Suppose a column vector $x$, and a function $f$ which accepts $x$ and returns a scalar. (e.g. [proposition 8](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEwQFjAA&url=http://www.atmos.washington.edu/~dennis/MatrixCalculus.pdf&ei=yUf7T5AE6u_SAe2u1cEG&usg=AFQjCNEAKf8-1P8R6o5gBFzmK0tIrNMnng&sig2=WU6J5K9-YKfyirNCOvoWoQ)). Then *suppose* that in the process of finding $\frac{\partial f }{\partial x} $, that you take the partial derivative with respect to $x_k$ to get the following,
$$\frac{\partial f }{\partial x_k} = 2x_k $$

so then, what is the derivative with respect to the entire vector $x$ (keeping in mind this is a hypothetical example and not the same as prop. 8)? I am not sure whether the the following result would be correct, and whether the result should a row or column vector.
$$\frac{\partial f }{\partial x} = 2x^T  $$

What if the function $f$ here returns a vector or matrix, then is the answer any different here?

Comment: So $\alpha$ is a function of $x$? Or of $x$ and additional variables?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is real valued, then you are right.

Comment: I assume $\alpha(\cdot)$ is a function of $x$; but it is unclear whether $\partial\alpha/\partial x=2x_k$ holds just for one $k$ or for all $k$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter here I mean for $\partial f / \partial x_k$ to hold for any $x_k$ in the vector, and also renamed it to $f$ since I now realize $\alpha$ by convention is a scalar constant instead of a function per se.

Answer (score 1):

It's depends on your definition, but usually the derivative of a scalar with respect to a vector is defined as
$\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial\mathbf{x}}
\equiv [\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x_1},\cdots, \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x_n}]^T
$
where $\mathbf{x}=[x_1, \cdots, x_n]^T$.

For your question, since $\mathbf{x}$ is a column vector and $\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x_k} = 2x_k$ holds for all $k$, then $\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial\mathbf{x}} = 2\mathbf{x}$, i.e. it's still a column vector by the above definition. (Of course, it can be a row vector by another definition.)

If $\alpha$ is a vector or matrix, then the result is a matrix or three-rank tensor, respectively. You can find more information at [here](http://www.colorado.edu/engineering/CAS/courses.d/IFEM.d/IFEM.AppF.d/IFEM.AppF.pdf) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) or google "matrix calculus".

Comment: for the first $\alpha/x_k$ it is just differentiating w.r.t. $x_k$, and for $\alpha/x$ it's just supposed to be w.r.t. $x$.

Comment: @T. Webster, is it a question or just a comment?

Comment: Just edited the answer according to your question modification.

Comment: @chohuang, so what I don't understand is why at (45) of proposition (8) (cf URL),  we go from a scalar expression $\partial \alpha/\partial x_k$, to an expression (46) $x^T$ instead of the $n \times 1$ vector  $x$